# I tried to rename photos to move them to another folder. What is wrong with my code that make File.renameTo(File) return false?

Tags: java, android, file

I tried to move a photo taken by the camera to a folder named "raspberrypi" I created. But the .renameTo() keeps returning false. I cannot find the reason. To clarify, the photos I am trying to move are taken by the camera, so they aren't in any folder to begin with.

**imagesEncodedList** is an ArrayList of File path Strings.

```
boolean bool=false;
for(int i=0; i<imagesEncodedList.size();i++){
   File from;
   File to=null;

   try{
       from=new File(imagesEncodedList.get(i));
       String dateString=new SimpleDateFormat("MM_dd_yyyy_HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
       to=new File(getPublicDir(),"SideBySide4_ImportedPhoto"+i+"_"+dateString+".jpg");
       bool=from.renameTo(to);
   }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
            new String[]{to.getPath()},
            null,
            null);
}
Toast.makeText(this, "Success?: "+bool, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
```

Here is my **getPublicDir()** function implementation:

```
public File getPublicDir() {
    // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "raspberry");
    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.e("PUBLIC DIRECTORY", "Directory not created");
    }
    return file;
}
```

Comment: Please do not use the code snippet for java since its not supported, I will edit your question without them.

Answer (score 1):

`renameTo` only works if source and target are on the same disk partition. If they're not, you'll have to copy the source file and delete it afterwards.

`context.getFilesDir()` is on a different partition (`/data`) than `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` (typically accessible under `/sdcard`).